# landscape to portrait

Tags: vertical-alignment, align

I'm working on landscape and I want only one page in portrait.

- How can I do that?

My workfile:

```
\documentclass[17pt,landscape,a4]{extarticle}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{animate}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts, amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\usepackage{rotating}

\pagenumbering{gobble}

\begin{document}
test
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the landscape package. Landscape mode will make you portrait. The headers will remain in their usual positions. Like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=1in,landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\begin{document}
Test (landscape page)
\begin{landscape}
Test (this is a portrait page)
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm curious, how did you discover this undocumented and very useful trick?

Comment: The landscape packages simply reverse the page dimensions, They don't make you landscape as such. As an aside the usual page dimensions are altered in a slightly idiosyncratic way - textheight becomes the old textwidth, but textwidth is left unchanged. linewidth is useful to size things.